# Does HTTPS protect from session riding?

Tags: security, http, session, ssl, cookies

In typical session riding scenario attacker makes victim machine to send HTTP request to web site they are already logged in, for example tricking victim to open link in the case of CSRF attack. Browser includes the session cookie (and all other cookies for that site) in the HTTP request, thus attacker can execute any - possibly malicious - operation victim is authorized to perform.

HTTPS encrypts the whole packet, thus making it impossible to read the content, including headers and cookies. But does it protect from session riding attacks, or will the browser still include the cookies and use correct encryption automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> will the browser still include the cookies and use correct encryption automatically?

[Yes](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)#HTTPS).  A CSRF attack works because the browser treats the request just like any other the user would normally want to make.  Both HTTP and HTTPS requests are sent as usual with all cookie data.  That's why it's up to the server side of the application to compensate with tokens.